# Problemas ao utilizar o Query Builder no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho manipulado os dados do BD com a criacao de Models, mas no meu projecto mais recente estou tendando fazer o uso de Query Builder, mas esta dando errado.

Gostaria entender o que esta faltando para que o codigo funcione perfeitamente. Para comecar declarei a facade use DB no meu controller. Aqui esta o código.

```
public function putente(Request $request)
{
     $putentes = DB::table('utentes')->where('nome',$request->get('putente'))->orWhere('bi_n', $request->get('putente'))->get();
     if(count($putentes)>0)
     {
         return view('home', ['putentes'=>$putentes]);
     }
 }
```

Na minha view tento pegar os dados dessa forma

```
{{$putentes->nome}}
```

Mas esta retornando esse erro

```
ErrorException in db040389b09b4e77a2f0e7fafa9a269acda44af2.php line 45:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\admc\resources\views\home.blade.php)
```

Existe algum problema de se utilizar nos projectos o Query Builder em vez de Models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da forma que você está fazendo `$putentes` é um array. É preciso iterar esses caras antes de acessar a propriedade `name`:

Assumindo que você está usando o Blade:

```
@foreach($putentes as $putente)
   {{$putente->nome}}
@endforeach
```

Sobre utilizar ou não o query builder depende muito do caso. Qual o seu motivo para não utilizar o Model?

Se você não tiver uma razão que se justifique, você só vai estar gerando mais código para fazer a mesma coisa que faria com o model.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, mas solucionei a questão adicionando o metodo first() no final da consulta, assim ele retorna apenas uma linha e não um conjunto de linhas em forma de Array.